# Create a class inside ProjectB that is executed first any time unit tests inside ProjectA are executed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, dependencies

I have a multi-project Spring Boot 2.7.0 based application.

ProjectA (`.war`) consumes the output from ProjectB (`.jar`).

Is there a way to create a class inside ProjectB that is executed first before unit tests inside ProjectA are executed?

I'd like to add `TestEmbeddedPostgresHelper` to ProjectB, so that when developers of ProjectA execute a unit test `TestEmbeddedPostgresHelper` will be executed beforehand ensuring a `Primary` `DataSource` exists.

Not sure of best practice for this version of SpringBoot, is it some configuration of `TestExecutionListener` on the class? Or using `spring.factories`?

```
import io.zonky.test.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

public class TestEmbeddedPostgresHelper {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestEmbeddedPostgresHelper.class);

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource inMemoryDataSource() throws Exception {
    log.info(
        "Starting embedded Postgres instance");
    DataSource embeddedPostgresDS = EmbeddedPostgres.builder().start().getPostgresDatabase();
    log.info("Embedded Postgres instance started for tests");
    return embeddedPostgresDS;
  }
}
```